# batch resize and crop images to a specific height and width

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, photoshop-scripting, actions

I have many images (TIFF, PNG, JPG...) and I want to resize them to 700 x 600 with 90% JPG quality, all at once using Photoshop actions.

I am able to resize them to fit the 700 x 600 but the resulting images are either 700 width only and less than 600 height or 600 height only and less than 700 width.

The catch here is that I have to resize them to the same resolution bigger than 700 x 600 then crop the rest of the extra width (sometimes the extra height) as the images have multiple Heights and multiple Widths.

Could someone assist me how to resize then crop them to maintain the aspect of the images with the exact 700 x 600 size?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your photos are a different aspect ratio.  If this is the case, then it's not possible to crop them without losing something. The alternative would be to distort the images to make them fit - which will look terrible.

When using the crop tool, type in the measurements in pixels that you require in the tool options along the top. Leave the resolution field blank - if there is a number in there, just delete it. Then use the crop tool to crop the image. You may lose a little part of the image.

Warning: if you automate this using actions, you will lose control of how the cropping is done. Probably best to do this manually. Also, make sure you are working on copies of the images and not the originals.

Comment: Thank you! I want to batch resize the images first then crop them to minimze the lost area and keep more details, is there another way to dot it with Imagemaick ? or another tool ?

Comment: @Abdelhafid You don't need to do that if you follow my instructions - the crop tool in Photoshop will resize the images to the exact size if you type in the pixel dimensions in the crop tool.

Comment: @Abdelhafid - when you type in the pixel dimensions make sure you type them in like "700 px" - so that Photoshop knows you mean pixels!